# Grid like styling with jquery Treeview

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, treeview, grid

in my project i have hierarchical data and i want to display it in following format

[image: Grid View]

i have just downloaded jquery treeview and tried it on a small ul. i want to know if i can make such a display with jquery treeview. if not please suggest some other controls. i m using asp.NET mvc 2 RTM with C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got data in List which contains the depth of each element in the list. the depth was then multiplied by some pixel value to show indentation. i had to write some javascript to implement expand and collapse functionality

Answer (score 0):

I definitely suggest [obout](http://www.obout.com/grid/aspnet_master_detail_onload.aspx) controls 
There are a lot of features of its grid controls.It's free,and so easy to control.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks Myra but it looks like web forms. i want some mvc thing

Comment: Sorry Muhammed,I assumed basicly in web forms